# C# Блокировка клавиатуры

Tags: c#

Создал программу которая выдает тесты для ученика а вот теперь нужно чтобы только мышка действовала а клавиатура не работала т.е её нужно заблокировать чтобы ученик не смог выходить или сворачивать программу.Чтобы любое нажатие клавиша игнорировалась.

Comment: а если ученики любят с клавиатуры выбирать результаты тестов?

Не нужно блокировать клавиатуру.

Или Вы верите в то, что если будет одна мышка, то ничего плохого не сможет сделать?

Какая цель запрета сворачивания? что бы не подсмотрел правильные ответы отдельно?

Comment: цель запрета в том что когда они сворачивают а это можно тока с клавы они заходят в соц сети и начинают переписываться просто нужно запретить печатать а. сворачивать уже заблочил

Comment: ага.

я бы лично делал по другому. Считал сворачивания. То есть, если совсем по тупому - то таймер, который раз в секунду проверяет состояние программы. Если она свернутая - считает время. Если время больше - то тест не пройден.
А если человек прошел тест, то пусть посидит в соцсети. С другой стороны, почему соцсети разрешены? админ быстрее запретит. И это будет правильно.

Comment: дело в том что ученик должен закончить тест а потом уже уйти не сворачиваю ничего т.е клава ваще не нужно я,думал может повесить глобальный хук?

Comment: а вообще реально заблокировать клаву в C#?

Comment: "а если ученики любят с клавиатуры выбирать результаты тестов?" дело в том что там checkbox сы и не надо работать ваще с клавой т.е выбрал нажал далее мне просто нужно полностью заблокировать клаву пока тест не будет пройден

Comment: хук повесить то не штука. вот только Ctrl+Alt+Del на современных виндах сложнее блокировать. Тем более на шарпе.

Comment: А вы собирайте клавиатуры перед началом теста:D

Comment: Моё мнение, если идти по-простому пути, сделать окно по верх всех остальных, а чтобы ещё не жаловались диспетчером, ловить потерю фокуса у окна и активировать его обратно. Свернут? Разверни, алттабнутся, верни обратно фокус. Таймер в пол секунды не даст соскучится пользователю.

Comment: "дело в том что там checkbox сы и не надо работать ваще с клавой" а я вот люблю вбивать чекбоксы таб+пробелом.